# Javascript event and function trigger

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to trigger the onclick event on the server and call a function (notBrowserClose()) on the client side.

```
  <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave0" runat="server"  OnClick="notBrowserClose(); ButtonSave_Click"  Text="Save all" Style="margin-left: 860px" Width="170px" />
```

This code doesnt work but you get the idea of what i want to do.

Comment: try below code....

Comment: share your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSave0" runat="server"  OnClientClick="notBrowserClose();" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click"  Text="Save all" Style="margin-left: 860px" Width="170px" />
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it didnt work, the function didnt get triggered.

Comment: @jANVI Could you elaborate what hou have changed?

Comment: added OnClientClick()

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish `OnClick` & `OnClientClick`, the former used for server-side event handler and the latter used for client-side JS event handler:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave0" runat="server" 
 OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" OnClientClick="notBrowserClose();" 
 Text="Save all" Style="margin-left: 860px" Width="170px" />
```

Reference:

[Button Class (System.Web.UI.WebControls)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have tried this and its not working,        function notBrowserClose() {

            browserClose = false;
            alert("tr");
            
        }
i had a break point but it didnt go in there..

Comment: @IbrahimAweidah Is that `alert("tr")` executed by showing message?

Comment: Not its not, Only the onbeforeunload method gets executed:

      function areYouSure() {
            if (allowPrompt) {
               
                var confMessage = "***************************************\n\n Before leaving the Budget page, please check that everything is saved.\n\n***************************************";
                    return confMessage;
            } 
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;

So after this alert i dont get the "tr" alert.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this using [jQuery click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)  as shown below :

```
 $('#<%=ButtonSave0.ClientID%>').click(function () {
        // your code goes here
        // if this alerts triggers your function is being called alright
        alert('i am here !');
        // is this a variable ??? may be you can declare it first ?
        browserClose = false; 
        alert("tr"); 
    });
```

Click() binds an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
Also you are using button's client id as shown in code above.

Hope this helps !